# get specific variable from ajax response using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax in javascript to get data into same page. but I need specific variables from my php page rather then whole response..

right now I am using,

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

that is fetching everything from that page.

Edited Code-PHP:

```
$currentscript = $clients->curr_group_content($_POST['group']);
$scriptscount = sizeof($currentscript);
                   for($i=0;$i<$scriptscount;$i++){
                        $script[] = $currentscript[$i]['subject'];
                        echo $script[$i];
                   }
echo "$scriptcount";
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Right now, I am getting all the data from $script and $scriptcount...
I want both of these but in separate manner.

Comment: so what have you tried in order to get a specific variable? Do you have any code that you can show us that you think should do the job, but doesn't work as you expect it to?

Comment: Rewrite your PHP script.

Comment: So, how do you expect anyone to help without showing them the information?

Comment: How  you are fetching everything? show some code

Comment: that depends on what is the PHP script returning

Comment: Just have your php page send back the variables in array format: var1,var2,var3,var4,etc then turn response into an array.

Comment: @GaryHayes: can you elaborate your answer please, I have edited some code.

Comment: hey everyone, there is an updated code now. thanks.

Comment: you could calculate scriptcount again client side with javascript. that way you don't need to echo scriptcount. however then I need to know what the value of script[i] is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your PHP output JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'scriptcount'=> $scriptcount,
    'script'=> $script
));
```

(do not echo anything else from your PHP)

Then in JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data.scriptcount;
```

Comment: first script you wrote on JSON, Do I need to put it in php page??

Comment: Yes, instead of `echo "$scriptcount";` And remove the other `echo` inside the loop.

Comment: Would it be same for if I want to print array instead of variable?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data.script`. You'll get a comma-separated strings with the value from the array.

Comment: Yes.. I am getting that. but, I have to separate it to put all that data into dropdownbox.. is there any way?

Comment: This is off-topic for your original question. I suggest you post a separate question about that, or find an existing answer (try googling "javascript create select from array").